# Autoresizing row of labels in Xcode has unexpected results

Tags: ios, xcode, label, autoresize

I'm having a problem using Autoresizing for the layout of a row of labels.

See image below.

[image]

I want first label to take up the entire width.
The label named "Lat:" will be narrow constant width aligned to left side.

The label named "Lon:" will be narrow constant width aligned horizontally in the center.

The labels "55.000" and "-95.000" will have variable widths basically filling in the space between display edges and the other labels ("Lat:" and "Lon:").

I thought I used the auto resizing constraints properly, but when the display is tilted to landscape, the auto resizing has unexpected results labels are overlapping each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using universal iOS app in Xcode 9.2

Comment: Post a pic of your constraints. Why are you using 4 labels instead of 2? Why not just set the label text to include "Lat:"? Do you know what a stackView is?

Comment: The constraints screenshots are depicted in the screenshot above. The narrow labels remain "Lat:" and "Lon:". The ones that are 55.0000 and -95.0000 are calculated in the app. Yes I know stack view, but I want the "Lat:" and "Lon:" labels to be narrow and the other two to change in width depending on the display used and it's orientation

Comment: That image doesn't give the value assigned to the constraints or the priority.

Comment: I'm not using constraints, but using autoresizing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using autoresizing, because you only have two options when positioning, either to pin a view at a fixed position or move it proportionally to the size. There is no way to pin it to the center position, so your third view will not position correctly as the size changes. Furthermore, the two views that have flexible width will be proportional to the parent view's width, while you really want them size the *same* amount as parent width / 2, so you can't get them to size perfectly.

To solve it you need to use either auto layout with constraints or do the layout by code in `layoutSubviews()`. Either of these are actually quite easy to solve your problem with.

UPDATE:
I tested it with dynamically changing the view size. This is what it looks like. First image is start condition, with view width of `300`. Second image is when width is changed to `600`. The values at the bottom is first the view width, then each of the four "segments" x position and width.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, the label placed horizontally in the middle (the dark green one) works very well and stays horizontally in the centre of the display.
It's the other two labels (light green and light yellow)  that don't seem to be able to resize themselves by keeping a fixed distance from the middle and leftmost label and the edges of the display.

Comment: I did a test where I dynamically changed the view width, and while it _looks_ like the third item sticks to the center, it doesn't. I will update my solution with screenshots of this.